# I’ve contact with

Tags: grammar

Hi there I'm new here and I have a question
I'm trying to send an e-mail to my managers told him that I have continue with another person as follows:

According to your request to me to start testing the” **********” I’ve contact with Mr. ****** and he told me that they are still testing this feature and I will get his feedback at next Monday .
Is this sentence correct

Comment: Proofreading is off-topic unless you raise specific concerns. That said, it should be "I have contacted Mr."

Comment: Dear MorganFR thank you for the correction ,What about the rest of the sentence

Comment: There are some more minor errors, however, this is not a site for proofreading, it is meant to help people learn about English. I suggest you take a look at http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/7571/where-can-i-ask-for-free-proofreading for some sites that can help you.

Comment: MorganFR tnx again

Comment: Welcome to ELL. You want the present participle, **telling**, not the past participle, **told**. And either singular manager|him or plural managers|them.  Also, "next Monday", not "at next Monday". And you want to say "follow up with" not "continue with".  If you have any specific questions about this advice, please ask a separate question on this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> According to your request to me to start testing the” **********” I’ve contact with Mr. ****** and he told me that they are still testing this feature and I will get his feedback at next Monday

As a style choice, this is a bit of a run-on sentence.  You could easily split it into three sentences, which will make checking grammar easier:

> 1) According to your request to me to start testing the *walrus helicopter*, I've contact Mr. *Whizzlebob*.
>
> 2) He told me they are still testing this feature.
>
> 3) I will get his feedback at next Monday

In Sentence 1, we can see that "contact" is not past-tense, and does not match "I have" or "According", which are past-tense.  I recommend changing "contact" to "contacted".

Sentence 2 seems fine to me.

Sentence 3 is missing a period at the end.

You've also got an odd phrasing in Sentence 3:  "I will [x] *at next* Monday."  In normal usage, "at" is used for time, and "on" is used for days.  Saying "I will [x] at 9AM next Monday" feels more correct.  You could also say "I will [x] on Monday."

The word "next" is also complicating things.  It is useful if there is some confusion about which Monday you mean, but it doesn't work with "at" or "on" - you would just say "I will [x] next Monday."

After making the suggested changes, your sentences should read as so:

> 1) According to your request to me to start testing the *walrus helicopter*, I've contacted Mr. *Whizzlebob*.
>
> 2) He told me they are still testing this feature.
>
> 3) I will get his feedback next Monday.

You could then reassemble them as in your first phrasing, as so:

> According to your request to me to start testing the *walrus helicopter*, I've contacted Mr. *Whizzlebob*, and he told me that they are still testing this feature and I will get his feedback next Monday.